# Increase the worth of my apple by 15% for every 1+ pear that I have

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

```
Apples: 1
Apple Value: 2500
Pears: lowest = 1, highest = 10
```

If I have 1 apple and my apple is worth **2500** if I have 1 pear, how can I calculate the value of my apple if I have X pears, at a maximum of 10 pears and a minimum of 1 pear, where 1 pear represents 100% value and 10 pears represents an increase of that value by 150%?

```
Apple Worth = 2500 * (1+((pears*15)/100))
```

This formula sort of works. The problem here is that if I have 1 pear, the value becomes `2500 * 1.15 = 2875` which is incorrect, as the value of my apple always is 100% of it's original value if I have at least 1 pear (pear count can never go below 1).

What am I missing here?

Edit:

Some clarification.

```
2500 = 1p = 100% (do not add 0.15 until p > 1)

2875 = 2p = 115%
3250 = 3p = 130%
3625 = 4p = 145%
4000 = 5p = 160%
4375 = 6p = 175%
4750 = 7p = 190%
5125 = 8p = 205%
5500 = 9p = 220%

5875 = 10p = 235% 

6250 = 11p = 250% (this is what 10p should be)
```

At 1 pear, my apple is worth 100% of it's original value, so this means that unless I have more than 1 pear, I can't add 0.15% per pear. The first pear is, in other words, not worth 0.15%, but rather 0%. This also means that the 10th pear should be 250% and not 235%.

Comment: Apple Worth $= 2500 * (1+(((\text{pears}-1)*15)/90))$

Comment: @P. Nick what exactly do you want the apple's value to be at 10 pears? $2500 \cdot 1.5$? Or $2500 \cdot (1+1.5)$? Taken literally, "increase of that value by 150%" means multiplying by $2.5$ ...

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Yes that's what I meant, but I thought it made more sense to write it as a 150% increase. But yes, the value should be multiplied by 2.5 at 10 pears, but only by 1 at 1 pear.

Comment: Also, do  you want the value of the apply to increase linearly as the pears go from $1$ to $10$? Or do you want it to grow exponentially? Or something else?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Although this does solve some parts of the formula; it doesn't quite fit what I was looking for. If I have for example 5 pears, then the multiplicator of my apple becomes `1.666666667` which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: What do you want the value to be at $5$ pears?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee The multiplicator should always increase by +0.15 per pear. 1 pear is +0, 2 pears is 0.15, 3 pears is 0.30 and so on. At 5 pears I expect it to be at `0.6`

Comment: @P.Nick OK, that is what is called "linear" growth

Comment: Can you make a table of the values you want to get for each pear ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit See my edit.

Comment: @P.Nick So do you want it to jump from $5500$ at $9$ pears to $6250$ at $10$ pears? I don't really know what you want the formula to do

Comment: $(6250 -2500)/375 = 10$ . It doesn't equal $9$. No formula anybody can write will change that fact :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the apple's value to be $2500$ at $1$ pear. There are two different ways to describe the linear growth of the apple's value for additional pears, depending on which of two conditions you want to impose.

---

**If you want the value to increase linearly for each additional pear, until it reaches $6250$ at $10$ pears**, then we can calculate the amount by which the value must increase, per pear.

Nine linear increases must make up the difference, so the amount by which the apple's value increases per pear must be $$\frac{6250-2500}{9} = 416.\overline{6}$$

The apple's value at $p$ pears for $1 \leq p \leq 10$, is then $$2083.\overline{3} +416.\overline{6}p$$

---

**If, instead, you want the value to increase by $15\%$ of $2500$, or $375$, for each additional pear**, then we have a different result:

At $p$ pears, for $1 \leq p \leq 10$, you want the value of the apple to be $$2500+(p-1)(0.15)(2500) = \boxed{2125 + 375p\,}$$

This means that at $10$ pears, the value of the apple is $5875$.

Comment: If I have 10 pears, the value of my apple then becomes `5875` which is equivalent to 9 pears. 10 pears and the value should be `6250`, if that makes sense. It's a tricky situation, because either I'm left with one pear too much, or one pear too few.

Comment: Can you make a list of the values you want for each $\#$ of pears?

Comment: (ideally, edit the original question to add the list)

Comment: I edited my post. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: You did get it right with the first method. I can get the desired result using any base, so I'm going to accept this answer. It's a tricky question though I can understand that.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{Apple Value} = 2500 \left( \frac{ 85+15p}{100} \right) .
\end{eqnarray*}
where $p$ is the number of pears.

Comment: Yes but this ends up at $5875$ at $p=10$ which apparently is blasphemy!!!!

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Oh goodness me, how dreadful ... but isn't that the value it should be ?

Comment: Honestly I have no clue what the question is any more, lol :)

Comment: We could use Lagrange interpolation ? @ZubinMukerjee

Comment: Yes that would work, if we knew what the values are supposed to be for each $p$ ... Is it supposed to be $$2500, 2875, 3250, 3625, 4000, 4375, 4750, 5125, 5500, 6250$$?????? I don't know.... @P.Nick do you want it to jump from 5500 to 6250 at 9 to 10 pears?

Comment: I've got it ... Lets use a Heaviside unit step function.